# StrictNullChecks and getElementById

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

With StrictNullChecks enabled in TypeScript 2.0, the code

```
var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('element_id');
```

produces the error

```
Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
```

Why is this and how can I get the code to compile without making `el` nullable?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can write:

```
var el = document.getElementById('element_id')!;
```

The ! means "trust me, this is not a null reference"

Comment: I've never seen this operator before...there seems to be very little documentation for it, but...great, elegant answer!

Comment: Cheers! yes don't remember where I saw that :p

Comment: I had no clue this existed.  This needs to be better documented.  I was avoiding strictNullChecks because of cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `document.getElementById(...);` can return an instance of `HTMLElement` if the element is found, or `null` if it is not. Since this API is not under your control, you will have to modify your code to allow the element to be nullable:

```
var el: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("...");
```

You can also create your own nullable type aliases:

```
type NullableHTMLElement = HTMLElement | null;
var el: NullableHTMLElement = document.getElementById("...");
```

Or better still you could use the solution provided by [AlexG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941384/alexg) which is even better!

Answer (score -1):

I know it's already late, I hope it will help someone else. For my scenario, I want to replace an input value... so the above answer threw one more error like "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'." So I tried like below and it worked for me.

```
const el = document.getElementById("my_el_id") as any;
if(el){ //Even this condition not required
  el.value = "New value";
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why your solution works?

Comment: Just use `document.getElementById<HTMLInputElement>("my_el_id")`. `any` has use cases, but this isn't one.