# document.getElementById("id") may be null

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Edit: I'm using TypeScript v2.2.1

I am new to TypeScript and I'm not sure what the cleanest way of dealing with DOM elements that may or may not exist is.  Basically, I want to check whether an element exists, and then if it does, add an event listener to it (I have `--strict_null_checks` turned on).

When I do it the JS-like way:

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('my-id');
if (myElement) {
  myElement.addEventListener('click', (e:Event) => {
    // Do stuff.
  });
}
```

I get the error `my_script.ts(3, 3): error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`

I can get around this by using a not-null assertion:

```
const maybeMyElement = document.getElementById('my-id');
if (maybeMyElement) {
  const myElement = maybeMyElement!;
  myElement.addEventListener('click', (e:Event) => {
    // Do stuff.
  });
}
```

But my understanding is that those sorts of assertions are generally frowned upon, and aesthetically, I don't like creating twice as many variables.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What version of the Typescript compiler are you using? Your first example works as expected for me (with `strictNullChecks` on).

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot to mention the version.  I'm using version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 34):

You should type your variables.  I haven't done a lot with `const`, but your second options seems plain wrong (code-smell).

You should be able to get around the warning by strictly typing the variable.  The compiler currently sees this as

```
const myElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('my-id');
```

If you change it to also possibly be null, then nulls are allowed:

```
const myElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('my-id');
```

**Updated**

Second option (that I haven't tried): use the `!` at the end of the potentially null operation, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640854/2084315

```
const myElement = document.getElementById('my-id')!;
```

Answer (score 6):

## Use Optional chaining "?"

Starting TypeScript version 3.7+ you can use [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

```
const maybeMyElement = document.getElementById('my-id');
maybeMyElement?.addEventListener('click', (e: Event) => {
  // Do stuff.
  console.log(e);
});
```

For older version of TypeScript we would do something like

```
const maybeMyElement = document.getElementById('my-id') as HTMLElement;
maybeMyElement.addEventListener('click', (e: Event) => {
  // Do stuff.
  console.log(e);
});
```

**Note:** Optional chaining (??) is always preferred over non-null assertion operator (!) as non-null assertion can actually lead to run time error if the value comes out to be null or undefined.

And, if you have "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended" configured in your eslint settings you will get "Forbidden non-null assertion" warning in your code.

Comment: Optional Chaining is super clean, thx.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following:

```
if (!!myElement) {
    myElement.addEventListener('click', (e:Event) => {
        // Do stuff.
    });
}
```

The `!!` coerces an object expression into a boolean.  It's the `!` operator twice.  For more info on this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: try editing your answer so I remove the downvote. I inadvertently clicked the downvote button by mistake and can't seem to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using referring to external JS file, then try adding "defer" in your script syntax.
eg:

```
<script src="./script.js" defer></script>
```